# How do the MATLAB functions plot and line differ?

Tags: matlab, plot, line

What's the difference between the functions `plot` and `line` in MATLAB? Are they doing the same thing?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The functions [`plot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html) and [`line`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html) do nearly the same thing, but `plot` is a high-level function that may have more interaction with other graphics objects. A brief summary of high-level and low-level functions can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/role-of-graphics-objects.html#bucf5dn-3). High-level functions like `plot` are likely internally calling primitive functions like `line` to create their graphics, but they can also modify or interact with properties of their parent [axes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes.html) or [figure](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure.html). From the documentation for [`line`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/line.html#bu748g2-5):

> Unlike the `plot` function, the `line` function does not call `newplot` before plotting and does not respect the value of the `NextPlot` property for the figure or axes. It simply adds the line to the current axes without deleting other graphics objects or resetting axes properties. However, some axes properties, such as the axis limits, can update to accommodate the line.

For example, if you call the `line` function:

```
line('XData', x, 'YData', y, 'ZData', z, 'Color', 'r');
```

MATLAB draws a red line in the current axes using the specified data values. If there is no axes, MATLAB creates one. If there is no figure window in which to create the axes, MATLAB creates it as well.

If you call the `line` function a second time, MATLAB draws the second line in the current axes without erasing the first line. This behavior is different from high-level functions like `plot` that delete graphics objects and reset all axes properties (except [`Position`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e56306) and [`Units`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e56630)). You can change the behavior of high-level functions by using the [`hold`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hold.html) command or by changing the setting of the axes [`NextPlot`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html#property_d0e55849) property.

The `plot` and `line` functions also differently affect automatic line coloring, as show [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45692196/52738).

Answer (score 2):

`plot()` is used to create a graphic, usually a line graph of some sort.  `line()` creates a lin object which may appear in, say, a graphic.  No they're not doing the same thing.  I'd usually use `plot` for creating a graphic, `line` for adding lines to an existing graphic.

If this doesn't answer your question, have a look at the documentation which covers these matters in great detail.

Comment: What do you mean by "a graphic?"